# Error: Metadata version mismatch for module .../node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/core.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3

Tags: angular, localization, ngx-translate

I followed the steps mentioned in the [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core) to support localization in some project, I've completed all the steps as mentioned, but when I tried to run the project I got the following error:

ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/someUser/Source/Repos/myProject/node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/core.d.ts, foundversion 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/someUser/Source/Repos/myProject/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModulein C:/Users/someUser/Source/Repos/myProject/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/someUser/Source/Repos/myProject/src/app/app.module.ts    at Error (native)    at syntaxError (C:\Users\someUser\Source\Repos\myProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34) ....

webpack: Failed to compile.

While @ngx-translate/core versions starts with version 6.0.

What is the problem?

Comment: What is your current angular and typescript version?

Comment: Angular 4, and Typescript 2.3.5

Comment: Is it possible to update the ngx-translate version? I think it's currently around 9. Not sure if it helps but it may help you out. I haven't checked the change log though

Comment: I 've already installed the last version, which is 9

Comment: Thanks guys, it was a packages compatibility problem, I’ve upgraded all to angular 5  (following this [guide](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/)), and every thing worked well.

Comment: @Hany Thanks for the guide it resolves my errors also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trials, I reached that it was a packages compatibility problem, I’ve upgraded all to angular 5 (following this [guide](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/)), and every thing worked well.

[image]